# How can I put lot of y label in an x label

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization

I was doing a training about data visualization. So in my data there is date and temperature values. Dates goes like 01-01-2000, 02-01-2000 .. till 12-01-2000. So for every date there is a temp value. But what I want to do is I want to put all values into an x label named as 2000. But when I try as you can guess it says 'x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (1,) and (12,)'. Is there anyway that I can do something about this ?

```
dates = ['2000']
values = [4.53, 4.425, 7.216, 9.04, 10.9, 14.312999999999999, 15.859000000000002, 16.160999999999998, 13.111, 8.366, 7.932, 5.0520000000000005]

plt.plot(dates, values)
plt.show()
```

> ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes
>   (1,) and (12,)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply make sure that `dates` also has 12 elements: `dates = ['2000'] * len(values)` (in this case, you will need to define `values` before `dates`.

Moreover, as you are discarding the month information, maybe a scatter plot would be more appropriate here.